# The max number of retries was performed. Upload ipa issue

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, application-loader

I have built ipa using build.phonegap.com. I am trying to unload this ipa to the store, but got this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. Install xCode 4. And use version application loader of this xCode 4. And this problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is network is not stable, change the network or restart Xcode(application-loader) trying.

[itc help](http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/itc8e7ec5a60)