# the max number of retries war performed. Application Loader Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, application-loader

I am trying to upload this ipa to the store, but got this error:

"The max number of retries was performed. The package will not be uploaded."

is there anything that can help me?
I use application loader 3.0

Comment: Which xcode version are you using? Also have a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/23756540/468724

Comment: @InderKumarRathore my Xcode version is 6.1.1, I've looked at the link you gave me, but it does not answer my problem naturally.

Comment: keep on searching and keep on trying..hope you solve your problem..

Comment: Hello, for me I just retried and it worked :x

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old question still I would like to answer this question.

For me same error occurred with Xcode 10.2 so I just tried again and it worked. There was no problem with my network. Hope this helps someone.